# Text box + submit button how do i send the string to another class

Tags: android

I am trying to create a class that allows search of a database to do this i am creating these classes.

- Search - search has a text box and a
  submit button. on submit it should
  send the text to DB.
- DB - DB handles the database
  connection and gets the result using
  the string it receives.
- Result - result will have a list
  activity view that will display the
  results revived from DB.

Thats how i want it to work.

At the moment i have this code.... and not much of it is working so i was hoping someone can tell me if im doing it wrong.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String   mSearch = search.getText().toString();

                trySearch(mSearch);
            }
        });
    }
```

how do i pass the mSearch string to my DB class, and run the method trySearch

Comment: When you say that you have 3 different classes do you mean activities? If so in order to pass data back and forth between them you can use startActivityForResult() @Rich linked this page on a different question a bit ago. You might find it helpful. It will show you how to use this to send data between activities. http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577

Comment: I assume that the DB class isn't an `Activity`, so you can simply pass `mSearch` as a parameter of a method.

Comment: sorry about my answer, i misunderstand the question :(

Comment: oh ok no worries im going to have a look at the example link that tim posted and see if that helps. it looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process the search string in your DB class, then simply use a setter/ getter system for this. Either link the butoon to the DB class using a get method that reads the content out of your textbox, or let the button set a parameter in your DB class.

Personally, I would let the DB class get the string on click.

Comment: oh my god everyone has different ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this (where MyDatabaseClass is your database class name):

```
MyDatabaseClass mdc = new MyDatabaseClass();
```

Then do

```
mdc.trySearch(mSearch);
```